# Help me with correct cpu / rom file

Tags: rom, cpu

I buy a phone from Ebay, i flashed the phone with wrong rom's in **Smart Phone Flash Tool**. then i flashed the phone i check the **Bootloader** off. so i don't flash the **preloader**.

I searched around and i found close to the phone and it was MT6735M without error in **Smart Phone Flash Tool**. But the phone still does not boot up, without success.

I asked on this forum i another topics, he help me to get **preloader.bin** out of my phone, now i have the **preloader.bin**.

> What the problem i can't found the right rom right now.

The name is: (**GSM UNLOCKED 4G LTE 6.29" Waterdrop Screen Smart Phone Android 9 Fingerprint ID**) from Ebay

i get confused:

```
Before i flash the Phone it says (MT6595)
I got booted it op in mode: and it says (MT6735)
The buyer says (MT6575)
WwR MTK says: CPU type: (MT6752)
```

Can some one help me with the right rom? i hope you also not get confused as i am. Tell me if you need more info about the topic.

Comment: according to your pictures this looks like a scam https://www.needrom.com/download/need-rom-for-indigi-p37 please watch this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjpO2vBeGcs if this is your phone, just ask for refund and send it back (don't tell them anything about the brick - scam the scammers)

Comment: most matching device seems the "Doogee X5 Max Pro x32" http://www.deviceinfohw.ru/devices/item.php?item=27651 so you can try twrp from this https://www.getdroidtips.com/lineage-os-14-1-on-doogee-x5-max-pro